# Command to highlight the occurrence of a method in a file?

Tags: search

How would I do the above?  Would it be different for each text editor?  Could it be done in the terminal?  Thanks

Comment: Do you just want to grep the file looking for the method names?

Comment: Yea, not sure what you mean by "highlight". Maybe you're referring to color schemes?

Comment: Are you using a text editor (if so, which) or the command line?

Comment: Command line.  I think grep is the right direction (I'm pretty new), but what would be the exact command to find all occurrences of a method in a file?  Idk if there is difference between finding a method or just any plain text block

Comment: @user49888 What language are the methods being written in? What's the syntax that identifies a method from other similar constructs?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a text editor, use your text editor's *search* command. For example, in `vim`, use <kbd>/</kbd> followed by the text you want to search for, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Pressing <kbd>n</kbd> goes to the next occurrence.

If you want to list all occurrences from the command line, use `grep`:

```
grep myMethodName filename.c
```

If you want a prettier display than grep, and more features, try [`ack`](http://beyondgrep.com):

```
ack myMethodName filename.c
```